# Get "Creator Owner" name to add access rule

Tags: .net, access-rights

I have a program in which I do the following

```
 oFolderACL.AddAccessRule(New Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(strDomaine & "\" & oUtilisateur.UserName, oAccessControl, Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags.None, oAccessType))
```

I would like to be able to do the same with the group CREATOR OWNER. Only problem is that depending of the computer I do it, the name can change so I can't use the name itself. Is there a way in .NET to retrieve the name (or identityreference) of this group ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the identity reference for the CREATOR OWNER using the SID:

```
IdentityReference identityReference = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-3-0");
```

There is a listing of the other "well known" SIDs here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330